# A Replacement for Java's Native Serialization

Tags: java, serialization

Use of Java's native serialization is kind of frowned upon these days, but is there a serialization library that is feature by feature equal to Java's native serialization? What I mean is that:

(Listed by priority)

1. Be able to serialize any (serializable) object (without the need for mapping, IDL, schema, etc.)
2. Serialize to binary format
3. Be stable/production ready
4. Be faster than Java's Native Serialization

I know variants of this question have been asked a few times on StackOverflow, but I couldn't find a conclusive answer, so I'm hoping to get some good conclusive answers this time.

Comment: I would be extremely surprised if there was anything that knew how to serialize any `Serializable` object that wasn't the normal Java serialization, though...

Comment: Yea, the only alternative I know of is JBoss Serialization, but hoping to see other ones on this post.

Comment: @Wasserman fast.serialization @ github does exactly this

Answer (score 5):

You could have a look at [Google Proto Buffer](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf/) or [Kryo](http://code.google.com/p/kryo/). GPB is stable and very fast, it also available in C++.
I did not use Kryo before but there's some benchmark look good.

Comment: Not sure about Kryo, but don't you have to define a schema per serializable class for Proto Buffers?

Comment: If you looking for a high performance serialization, a schema per serializable class should work better, because it don't have to travel around the class. GBP required a message struct pre-define then a compile translate it to a java class.

Comment: I'm not necessarily looking for the fastest approach, that's why it's #4 on the list.

Comment: @Drew We use Kryo specifically because it does NOT require any predefined schema and supports custom serialisation. Very nice library. Before it we were using XStream (XML) for a similar reason, but Kryo has much better performance and size (binary).

Answer (score 2):

https://github.com/RuedigerMoeller/fast-serialization

is pretty close to what you are looking for. It supports all JDK-Serialization special methods, so you can try without lots of code change.

Comment: R.Moeller, Is it possible to use FST for converting Strings to List of nested Lists? For example input string is "[[1.0,2.0],[5.0,3.0]]" and as result I'll have List, that contains two nested Lists, which contains doubles. I can achieve this with Gson and Jackson, but probably Your tool can do this faster?

Comment: @dimson fst focusses on generic serialization (binary, json). There is also kson (rarely documented), however this one is used for config files (text to object ~yaml style) and not optimized for speed

Comment: Ok, thanx for answer, I understand.

Answer (score 0):

If you are concerned about performance as well as productivity, you can consider [Babel](https://computation.llnl.gov/casc/components/#page=home). Using Babel and an additional sidl file (which looks like a Java interface) you can transparently invoke functions defined in C, C++, Fortran, Python, etc. from Java and vice versa. Babel will handle serialization behind the scenes.

Comment: I don't think Babel meets requirement #1

Comment: @Drew true, I was assuming your goal is to invoke native functions. If those functions are exposed in a sidl (idl) file, you can invoke them from Java passing corresponding Java objects. Babel handles glue code generation and serialization behind the scenes.

Answer (score 0):

This project compares performance of a range of serialization techniques.  Note: It lists Externalizable (which uses Java Serialization) as the fastest,

http://code.google.com/p/thrift-protobuf-compare/wiki/Benchmarking

I did a performance comparison with a faster technique, but it is harder to get right than Externalizable and I wouldn't recommends it unless you need ultra-low latency.

http://vanillajava.blogspot.com/2011/10/serialization-using-bytebuffer-and.html

The real questions is; How much effort is it worth to make it faster?  If you are looking for a quick win, I suspect you will be disappointed.  If you are willing to put in some effort, you can make significant improvements.

I would like at using Externalizable first because you can convert a few key classes (the ones which take most of the time now) and leave most of the classes unchanged.  i.e. It may allow you to get the best of both worlds.

Comment: I'm not looking for the fastet approach per se. Since I won't know what object will be serialized ahead of time, it's hard to optimize a few classes. The list of requirements that I have is prioritized but importance of the requirement.

Comment: It is possible that Java Serialization is the best choice if you have no information about which classes may need to be serialized. All the other approaches require optimisation of specific classes.

Comment: Generic serialization can be better/on par with manual serialization if you manage to reuse streams correctly. See http://java-is-the-new-c.blogspot.de/2013/10/still-using-externalizable-to-get.html

Comment: @R.Moeller It depends on your use case but for heavily optimised serialization you want to recycle all your objects (not create any new ones) and get around 100 ns delay.

Comment: @Peter if run in unshared mode (no hashing for cycles) and reuse of streams there should be zero allocation after the first 2-3 objects. Even with cycle detection maps will be reused (maybe once in a while an alloc may happen in that case though ;-) ).

Comment: @Peter Addition: just do *NOT* use externalizable, then the generic serialization is pretty much the same as your hand written stuff, but done in a loop instead of being unrolled like you do manually. Metadata gets prepared once in advance ofc.

Comment: @R.Moeller If performance doesn't concern you, use Java Serialization, but if you care about performance, almost any option is better. https://code.google.com/p/thrift-protobuf-compare/wiki/Benchmarking Does an extra loop explain the performance difference? I don't think so.

Comment: @Peter i actually contributed those benchmarks you are referring to ;-) (protobuf forwards to github bench). https://github.com/eishay/jvm-serializers/wiki. Note that Protobuf does not support cycle detection/shared refs. So its a tree encoder not a serializer. Generic Serializers like FST-fast-serialization and Kryo come pretty close to that. If you have a broad range of not-trivial interlinked data structures you are frequently better off using a full-featured fast serialization. If its only a flat list of say trades or orders, you might be like 10%, but depends a lot on the data ..